# Calculating the exact needed height for a QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtablewidget

I want to calculate the exact height a `QTableWidget` needs so that no vertical scroll bar is shown. What I do right now is for example:

```
tableWidget->setMaximumHeight(tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->height()
                              + tableWidget->rowHeight(0) * 4
                              + 4);
```

for this case, having 4 rows of the same height and KDE's Breeze style set, this works exactly:

[image: Widget shown with KDE's Breeze style]

But the additional 4 pixels seem to be style-dependent, using the Fusion style I get a bit more space than I need (cf. the last row, there are 2 unneeded white pixels):

[image: Widget shown with the Fusion style]

Is there a way to calculate the exact needed size independently of or better considering the style?

Comment: You can check the current style(or just set the style programmatically) and based on that,set the **+4** offset to **0** if the style is **fusion** for example.You can check the current style via ```QApplication::style()``` or set it via ```QApplication::setStyle()```.

Comment: Well, using this approach, I would have to handle all styles … I need to be able to calculate the addition without knowing which style is in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can get tableWidget's height with "tableWidget->viewport()->height()" .

Regarding the vertical scrollbar, you can use this functions.

```
setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
Then, the vertical scrollbar will be permanently hidden.
```

Comment: Maybe the viewport height could actually help … I'll check out if the widget's height minus the viewport height is the needed pixel addition. Thanks for the hint for now :-)

Comment: The needed additional pixels are actually (widget->height() - widget->horizontalHeader()->height() - widget->viewport()->height()). Thanks a lot :-)